# How to handle this URL Structure. Keep getting "page not found"

Tags: urls, rewrite-rules

I have created two Custom Post Types, named `"test"` and `"articles"`.

I am trying to achieve below URL structure:

1. site.com/test/post-title - for post type `test`. Works fine.
2. site.com/test/articles/post-title - for post type `articles`

As you see this one has "test" (name of first cpt) prepended. Trying to access a post returns "Page not found".

I have `updated permalinks` from `Admin > Settings > Permalinks`.

At a time of custom post type `"articles"` registration I declared:

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'test/articles')`

Is There a way to handle this URL format?

UPDATE:

```
$args = array(
    'has_archive' => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'label'  => __( 'Test', 'domain'),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author )
);

register_post_type( 'test', $args );

$args = array(
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'label' => __( 'Articles', 'domain' ),
    'supports'  => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author' ),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'test/articles')
);

register_post_type( 'articles', $args );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that anytime you try and go to a post such as:

```
http://example.com/test/articles/example-slug/
                    ↑      ↑
                    |      └ attempts to match "articles" as name/pagename query variable 
                    └ matches post_type "test"
```

WordPress is trying to match `/test/articles`, as in `articles` being a post of `post_type === test`.

Instead you need to add a custom rewrite rule (then flush your rewrite rules):

```
function wpse221472_custom_rewrite_rules() {

  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^test/(articles)/(.*)?', 
    'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]', 
    'top'
  );

}

add_action('init', 'wpse221472_custom_rewrite_rules');
```

This will match:

```
                       $matches[1]  $matches[2]
                           ↓            ↓
http://example.com/test/articles/example-slug/
```

Not sure that this is the best approach but it will work, just be aware that you cannot have a post unde the `test` `post_type` that has a slug of `articles` because it won't be matched; our re-write rule will override it.

If that doesn't bother you then the above should suffice.

Comment: I applied these rewrite rules. Now, when I enter a post url for example `test/articles/article-post-1` instead of single page I get the archive page for type Articles containing list of posts.

Comment: Show me your `register_post_type` code for both post types... you are close, but something is amiss.

Comment: Updated the question with relevant code.

Comment: Use the code found here: http://pastebin.com/Aw8d7sv9 - I do not have any issue. Try uncommenting the call to `flush_rewrite_rules()` found in the rewrite rule callback...

Comment: No worries... make sure you comment out the call to `flush_rewrite_rules()` again as you don't want that running each request unnecessarily. Enjoy!